# Add custom elements and attributes to compiler schema

Tags: angular, angular2-compiler

There are some custom elements and attributes in component template (in this example they are used by third-party non-Angular code):

```
<foo></foo>
<div data-bar="{{ bar }}"></div>
```

They cause a compiler error:

```
Template parse errors:
'foo' is not a known element:
1. If 'foo' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'foo' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    [ERROR ->]<foo></foo>
    <div data-bar="{{ bar }}"></div>
  "): App@1:4
Can't bind to 'bar' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    <foo></foo>
    <div [ERROR ->]data-bar="{{ bar }}"></div>
  ")
...
```

How can `foo` element and `data-bar` attribute be added to compiler schema?

`NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` is not an option because it is not desirable for other unknown elements and attributes to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to override `DomElementSchemaRegistry` like this:

```ts
import { DomElementSchemaRegistry, ElementSchemaRegistry } from '@angular/compiler'
import { SchemaMetadata } from '@angular/core';

const MY_DOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA = [
  'foo'
];

const MY_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES_SCHEMA = {
  'div': {
    'bar': 'string'
  }
};

export class CustomDomElementSchemaRegistry extends DomElementSchemaRegistry {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  hasElement(tagName: string, schemaMetas: SchemaMetadata[]): boolean {
    return MY_DOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA.indexOf(tagName) > -1 || 
         super.hasElement(tagName, schemaMetas);
  }

  hasProperty(tagName: string, propName: string, schemaMetas: SchemaMetadata[]): boolean {
    const elementProperties = MY_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES_SCHEMA[tagName.toLowerCase()];
    return (elementProperties && elementProperties[propName]) || 
        super.hasProperty(tagName, propName, schemaMetas);
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{ provide: ElementSchemaRegistry, useClass: CustomDomElementSchemaRegistry }]
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qWGOq154KgxxgcxBXh9t?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, good one! I was pretty sure that DomElementSchemaRegistry class is internal. Btw, it has to be `!!(elementProperties && elementProperties[propName])`.

Comment: Perhaps something has changed in later Angular versions, but I am not apparently able to bootstrap the module in this way.  TBH, I've rarely-if-ever done anything fancy with the bootstrapping so it could just be that I don't understand.  In trying to follow this answer, I'm receiving an error because, apparently, the argument passed into bootstrapModule does not match its expected type.  I've attempt to Stackblitz it at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-custom-elements-and-attributes-to-compiler-schema?file=src/main.ts

Answer (score 1):

Looking good, but notice in you Plunker Example, the div in the markup is as below:

```
data-bar="{{ bar }}"
```

bar being = "test" is outputting on the dom just as:

```
<div></div>
```

and not

```
<div data-bar="test"></div>
```

If you want the attribute rendered - say for polymer components you can use the following.

```
[attr.data-bar]="bar" in the markup
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but if you're suggesting that `data-bar="{{ bar }}"` could be replaced with `data-bar="test"`, then no, it's not possible - the whole point of the question is how custom attribute can be dynamic. `bar` doesn't change in the example, but this was made for simplicity.

Comment: {{bar}} is the dynamic value for attribute data-bar in @yurzui example. my question is to have that attribute rendered on the DOM with its value set, and not just have <div> </div> rendered

Comment: Sorry nevermind - got it - [attr.data-bar]="bar" and angular will be able to set the attr dynamically to render, above example useful if you dont want to enable all elements as you say using CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Comment: Conor is right. Even if we add data-bar attr as exclusion for element schema  - Angular removes attribute at final render (so div has no bar attr at all)

Answer (score 0):

Injecting CustomDomElementSchemaRegistry works now-a-days a little-bit differently:

**JIT compiler**

The injector has changed since the previous answer, so the type *signature changed* a very little.
From version 5 `StaticInjector` needs the deps array with useClass (Angular 8.2)

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, 
 {
   providers: [
    { 
       provide: ElementSchemaRegistry, 
       useClass: CustomDomElementSchemaRegistry, 
       deps: [] 
    }
   ]
 }
);
```

**AOT compiler**

We can *NOT* use the injector for ahead of time compilation, but there is a possiblity to "monkey-patch" the class `DomElementSchemaRegistry` before it is instantiated by the compiler, for a detailed description check it here:

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-elementschemaregistry-for-dummies-83d54cd31478

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain further what this answer adds to the code from the accepted one? It seems the only thing that is different is `deps: []`, which isn't used for class providers. It's true that there's static injector in A5, but legacy reflective injector wasn't used in previous solution, so I'd expect it to be still relevant.

Comment: Sorry, it is not complete yet. The compilerOptions has a type signature which compiles with angular 8.2, but the custom class may not called. I'll mark it on the answer itself. Its an answer to Dan Overlander, where I could put in code example.